# When I do command as "npm install" it comes ERRORs ( This code folder was download from GitHub)

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: berry-material-react-free@3.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.8.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-16T10_57_14_537Z-debug-0.log

Can anyone help me for solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to inconsistent versioning inside the node packages. You can use the following command to ignore the versioning

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Note that this is not the best solution since it might cause some behavior discrepancies in node packages. Best way is to figure out proper versioning to dependencies

Comment: Thankyou so much. When I use "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" command that error solved.

Comment: @TharuSalgado no problem. please mark as checked if this answer your question