# Google App Engine deploy package.json file with --force option?

Tags: reactjs, npm, google-app-engine, npm-install

I am trying to deploy a Next project to Google Cloud, App Engine. My deployment script I have used before works just fine, however I do have a conflict in my package.json (outdated dependencies). This actually does not break the project, it works with --force flag, however Google App Engine complains about it.

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 110 files to Google Cloud Storage              ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                       
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 8ed3506e-7530-4d75-8d08-87072f7d6d42 status: FAILURE
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-elastic-carousel@0.11.5
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18" from @prismicio/next@1.3.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@prismicio/next
npm ERR!     @prismicio/next@"^1.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   10 more (@prismicio/react, @slicemachine/adapter-next, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"15 - 17" from react-elastic-carousel@0.11.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-elastic-carousel
npm ERR!   react-elastic-carousel@"^0.11.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"15 - 17" from react-elastic-carousel@0.11.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-elastic-carousel
npm ERR!     react-elastic-carousel@"^0.11.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /www-data-home/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-09-04T09_52_37_972Z-debug-0.log
```

I guess this is because the deploy script on Google does `npm ci` which I have no way to overwrite it seems?

Comment: Can you check with the suggestion shared in [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74459921/18265702). This seems due to inconsistent versioning inside the node packages. You can try running the following command `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni Thank you, but sadly it did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can try with the suggestions in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71582397/18265702). Also make sure the dependencies installed in the `package.json` file should be compatible with your npm version.